# FindRoot with a big range

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, mathematical-optimization

I have a variable `sig` that is related to the variables `(b,zQ,zh)` given by `torootsig`, so I can solve this `sig` from the corresponding values of `(b,zQ,zh)`. I setup a `FindRoot` of their relation for later input of the variables `(b,zQ,zh)`.

Now, I have a function `SQ` where I want to find its minimum value at some point `zQ`. The function `SQ` is a function of `(sig,b,zQ,zh)`, but since `sig` can be written as a function of `(b,zQ,zh)`, `SQ` can just be written in terms of `(b,zQ,zh)`.

The values of the variables are, `b=0.1`, `0.1<zh<0.9`, and `zQ` is the one I am finding.

```
d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 20;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
torootsig[b_?NumericQ, sig_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, sigr, zQr, zhr}, {br, sigr, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, sig, zQ, zh}, 0]; br - NIntegrate[z^d/Sqrt[f[z, zhr] (zQr^(2 d) (1 + (sigr^2/f[zQr, zhr])) - z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
sig[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := sig /. FindRoot[torootsig[b, sig, zQ, zh], {sig, -0.3, -1.5, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 100]
intSQ1[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-1/(d - 1)) (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) NIntegrate[z^d Sqrt[f[z, zhr]/(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
intSQ2[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-1/(2 zhr^(d + 1))) ((d + 1)/(d - 1)) NIntegrate[z Sqrt[(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))/f[z, zhr]], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
intSQ3[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (1/zhr)^(d + 1) NIntegrate[z/Sqrt[f[z, zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
SQ[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-Sqrt[f[zQr, zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) zQr^(2 d))]/((d - 1) zQr^(d - 1)) + intSQ1[br, zQr, zhr] + intSQ2[br, zQr, zhr] + intSQ3[br, zQr, zhr] + 1/zQr^(d - 1))/4 ]
```

If I plot `sig` for `zh=0.1` and `zh=0.9`, then I get

```
Plot[sig[0.1, zQ, 0.1], {zQ, 0.0994, 0.1}, PlotPoints -> 3, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large] // AbsoluteTiming(*{sig,-0.008,-0.2,0}*)
```

[image: Image1]

```
Plot[sig[0.1, zQ, 0.9], {zQ, 0.54, 0.9}, PlotPoints -> 3, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 24], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large] // AbsoluteTiming(*{sig,-0.5,-2,0}*)
```

[image: Image2]

Take note of the range of `sig` for the extremes of `zh`, i.e. `zh=0.1` and `zh=0.9`.

If I apply `FindMinimum` for each case say, `zh=0.1` and `zh=0.9`, and choose the range of `sig` in the `FindRoot` **carefully**, then I can find the minimum at some `zQ`.

```
FindMinimum[SQ[0.1, zQ, 0.1], {zQ, 0.0995, 0.0999}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
{41.70848808, {zQ -> 0.09987512204}}

FindMinimum[SQ[0.1, zQ, 0.9], {zQ, 0.83, 0.86}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
{0.2745876051, {zQ -> 0.8454219108}}
```

However, If I try to apply `FindMinimum` for several values at the same time, say `zh` spanning from `0.1` to `0.9` with an interval of `0.1`, then Mathematica complains since if I choose a range that cover `0.1<zh<0.9`, it seems like it is too big of a range for Mathematica to converge to the minimum, especially if I choose a starting point that is closer to `zh=0.1`, then it will complain about values closer to `zh=0.9` and vice versa.

```
Table[FindMinimum[{SQ[0.1, zQ, zh/10]}, {zQ, 0.96 (zh/10), 0.93 (zh/10), 0.999 (zh/10)}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 100], {zh, 1, 9, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming(*zQ for zh=0.1 to zh=0.9*)

FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than 20.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than 20.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than 20.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation.

FindMinimum::reged: The point {0.093} is at the edge of the search region {0.093000000000000000000,0.099900000000000000000} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than 20.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than 20.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than 20.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

General::stop: Further output of FindMinimum::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Is there any way to apply `FindRoot` and `FindMinimum` for a big range? I have also tried using a big working precision, say 500, but still the same error so I just reverted back to 20 since it just took a longer time anyways.

Comment: I cannot find a question being asked in this post. Can you, please, edit your post and clearly state your question?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your first plot.  Please confirm that the code is correct.  I can, however, reproduce your second plot.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You can use the range `{sig,-0.008,-0.2,0}` for `FindRoot` to obtain the first plot. See the comment at the end of the code for the first plot.

Comment: Likewise, I am unable to reproduce the results of your first `FindMinimum` call, Instead receiving a string of error messages.  Please confirm that the code is correct.  I can reproduce the results of your second call.

Comment: @mathemania  Yes, that change reproduces your first plot and also the results of your first call to `FindMinimum`.  I suggest that you modify your question to make clear the specific parameters you used to call `FindRoot`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey But that is exactly my question, I need to specify carefully the range of `FindRoot` otherwise Mathematica complains, and the error if the range is too big is already showed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "silver bullet" that allows `FindRoot` to work well independent of the initial guess and allowed range.  However, some modest changes to a portion of the code solves the problem at hand:

```
sig[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
    sig /. FindRoot[torootsig[b, sig, zQ, zh], {sig, -0.008, -1.5, 0}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
    MaxIterations -> 100]
```

and

```
Table[FindMinimum[SQ[0.1, zQ, zh/10], {zQ, 0.995 (zh/10), 0.93 (zh/10), 
    0.999 (zh/10)}, AccuracyGoal -> ag/2, PrecisionGoal -> pg/2, 
    WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 100], {zh, 1, 9}]

(* {{41.708488082871755339, {zQ -> 0.099875122173899104886}}, 
    {7.3882696485627023476, {zQ -> 0.19730320573040630212}}, 
    {2.8757698770873017009, {zQ -> 0.29157451761998630781}}, 
    {1.5166624430845260746, {zQ -> 0.38432981366296936968}}, 
    {0.93669614150771657618, {zQ -> 0.47655732465217074490}}, 
    {0.63663715445176335400, {zQ -> 0.56867227658480048990}}, 
    {0.46128372679685788584, {zQ -> 0.66082912902815081500}}, 
    {0.34985408866400740299, {zQ -> 0.75307646956556178437}}, 
    {0.27458760506030462097, {zQ -> 0.84542190572477149758}}} *)
```

The primary error messages given in the question appear to result from the following:

> > FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than 20.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

occurs in this question, because the definition of `sig` appears to fail for zQ too small, so we must avoid that region.

> > FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than 20.` digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

occurs in this question, because `FindRoot` produces input to `FindMinimum` with precision `pg` (at best), so we should not be surprised if `FindMinimum` produces output with precision less than that.  Asking for a lower precision solves the problem.

As a sidelight, here is a plot of `sig` vs zQ/zH`.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[sig[0.1, n z, n], {n, .1, .9, .1}], {z, .5, 1}, 
    Frame -> True, PlotPoints -> 3, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
    PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large,
    FrameLabel -> {"zQ/zH", "sig"}]
```

[image]

Avoid regions where `sig` is zero.

Comment: Just a side question, why is it that precision is poor for `sig=0`? It's still a number right?

Comment: @mathemania  I was mistaken.  Some experimentation reveals instead that `FindRoot` convergence sometimes is too slow there.  I deleted my last sentence.  By the way, I plotted, `Plot[sig[0.1, zQ, 0.1], {zQ, 0.099123, 0.099124}, ImageSize -> Large]`, which shows a discontinuity.  I do not have time to investigate why, or even if it matters.

Comment: Your analysis really helped me understand the problem, however, when I use your code to plot, Mathematica complains `The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function`. So this means that it can show the plot but with accuracy and precision less than what I imposed right?

Comment: @mathemania  By experimentation, I have found that this error only occurs for your question when `Plot` tries to evaluate points for `sig` equal to zero.  Because `SQ` is not maximized there, such points should be of no interest, I believe.