# Increment FindMinimum range

Tags: mathematical-optimization, procedural-programming

I have a function `SQ[b,zQ,zh]` where I want to find at which `zQ` it is a minimum. The parameters are `b=0.1`, `zh=(0.1,0.9)` increment by `0.1` so `zh` has 9 values.

```
d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 20;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
torootsig[b_?NumericQ, sig_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, sigr, zQr, zhr}, {br, sigr, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, sig, zQ, zh}, 0]; br - NIntegrate[z^d/Sqrt[f[z, zhr] (zQr^(2 d) (1 + (sigr^2/f[zQr, zhr])) - z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
sig[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := sig /. FindRoot[torootsig[b, sig, zQ, zh], {sig, -2 zh, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 100]
intSQ1[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-1/(d - 1)) (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) NIntegrate[z^d Sqrt[f[z, zhr]/(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
intSQ2[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-1/(2 zhr^(d + 1))) ((d + 1)/(d - 1)) NIntegrate[z Sqrt[(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))/f[z, zhr]], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
intSQ3[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (1/zhr)^(d + 1) NIntegrate[z/Sqrt[f[z, zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 20]]
SQ[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (-Sqrt[f[zQr, zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) zQr^(2 d))]/((d - 1) zQr^(d - 1)) + intSQ1[br, zQr, zhr] + intSQ2[br, zQr, zhr] + intSQ3[br, zQr, zhr] + 1/zQr^(d - 1))/4 ]

FindMinimum[SQ[0.1, zQ, 0.1], {zQ, 0.0993, 0.0999}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
{41.70848808, {zQ -> 0.09987512206}}

0.09987512206/0.1
0.9987512206

FindMinimum[SQ[0.1, zQ, 0.2], {zQ, 0.195, 0.199}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
{7.388269649, {zQ -> 0.197303209}}

0.197303209/0.2
0.986516045

FindMinimum[SQ[0.1, zQ, 0.3], {zQ, 0.29, 0.299}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
{2.875769877, {zQ -> 0.291574518}}

0.291574518/0.3
0.97191506

FindMinimum[SQ[0.1, zQ, 0.4], {zQ, 0.35, 0.4}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
{1.516662443, {zQ -> 0.3843298312}}

0.3843298312/0.4
0.960824578

FindMinimum[SQ[0.1, zQ, 0.5], {zQ, 0.45, 0.5}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
{0.9366961415, {zQ -> 0.4765573324}}

0.4765573324/0.5
0.9531146648

FindMinimum[SQ[0.1, zQ, 0.9], {zQ, 0.83, 0.86}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 20]
{0.2745876051, {zQ -> 0.8454219108}}

0.8454219108/0.9
0.9393576787

Table[FindMinimum[SQ[0.1,zQ,n/10],{zQ,(93/100) (n/10),(999/1000) (n/10)},AccuracyGoal->ag,PrecisionGoal->pg,WorkingPrecision->wp,MaxIterations->100],{n,1,9,1}]//AbsoluteTiming
```

I have found at which `zQ` is the minimum for the two extreme values of `zh`. For `zh=0.1` the minimum is at around `zQ ~ 0.998 zh`, for `zh=0.9` the minimum is at around `zQ ~ 0.939 zh`.

The problem is as `zh` goes to lower values `FindMinimum` will fail for some `zQ` and below. For example, for `zh=0.1`, the range I put in `FindMinimum` is `{zQ, 0.0993, 0.0999}` but if I change the `zQmin=0.0993` to `zQmin=0.098`, `SQ` will fail there.

My question is, is there a way to write a code to increment `zQmin` from some value to some higher value (in this case `zQmin = {(93/100) (n/10), (994/1000) (n/10)}`) so that when `FindMinimum` fails it will increment until `FindMinimum` does not fail. I'm not sure if I'm framing this problem correctly, I was also thinking of maybe `Conditionals` like `If, For, While`. My end goal is to execute the `Table` written above.

My related post will be useful,
[FindRoot with a big range](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253729/findroot-with-a-big-range).

Answer (score 1):

In the line `Table[FindMinimum[SQ[0.1,zQ,n/10],{zQ,(93/100) (n/10),(999/1000) (n/10)}],{n,1,9,1}]` only cases `n=1,2` are problematic due to  `FindRoot` since there are no roots for some parameters. For `n>=3` we have (all options with `ag, pg, wp` have been omitted)

```
d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 20;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
torootsig[b_?NumericQ, sig_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{br, sigr, zQr, zhr}, {br, sigr, zQr, zhr} = 
    Rationalize[{b, sig, zQ, zh}, 0]; 
   br - NIntegrate[
     z^d/Sqrt[
       f[z, zhr] (zQr^(2 d) (1 + (sigr^2/f[zQr, zhr])) - 
          z^(2 d))], {z, 0, zQr}]];
sig[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
  x /. FindRoot[torootsig[b, x, zQ, zh], {x, -2 zh, 0}, 
    MaxIterations -> 1000];
intSQ1[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = 
    Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 
     0]; (-1/(d - 
        1)) (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + 
          sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) NIntegrate[
     z^d Sqrt[
       f[z, zhr]/(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + 
                 sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, 
      zQr}]];
intSQ2[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = 
    Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 
     0]; (-1/(2 zhr^(d + 1))) ((d + 1)/(d - 1)) NIntegrate[
     z Sqrt[(1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + 
                 sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))/
        f[z, zhr]], {z, 0, zQr}]];
intSQ3[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = 
    Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 0]; (1/zhr)^(d + 1) NIntegrate[
     z/Sqrt[f[z, 
         zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + 
                 sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/f[zQr, zhr]))) z^(2 d))], {z, 0, 
      zQr}]];
SQ[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{br, zQr, zhr}, {br, zQr, zhr} = 
   Rationalize[{b, zQ, zh}, 
    0]; (-Sqrt[
        f[zQr, zhr] (1 - (1/(zQr^(2 d) (1 + 
                  sig[br, zQr, zhr]^2/
                   f[zQr, zhr]))) zQr^(2 d))]/((d - 1) zQr^(d - 1)) + 
     intSQ1[br, zQr, zhr] + intSQ2[br, zQr, zhr] + 
     intSQ3[br, zQr, zhr] + 1/zQr^(d - 1))/4]
Table[
  FindMinimum[
   SQ[0.1, zQ, n/10], {zQ, (93/100) (n/10), (999/1000) (n/10)}], {n, 
   3, 9, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {19.1095, {{2.87577, {zQ -> 0.291575}}, {1.51666, {zQ -> 
     0.38433}}, {0.936696, {zQ -> 0.476557}}, {0.636637, {zQ -> 
     0.568672}}, {0.461284, {zQ -> 0.660829}}, {0.349854, {zQ -> 
     0.753076}}, {0.274588, {zQ -> 0.845422}}}}
```

In a case of `n=1` we can plot

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[torootsig[.1, x, y, .1], {y, .093, .0999, .0011}]], {x, -.01, 
  0.01}, PlotRange -> {-.05, .05}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

There are no roots in a range of `0.093<=xQ<=0.098` it is why we have messages from `FindRoot`, `NIntegrate` and `FindMinimum`.  To solve this problem we can use

```
cp = ContourPlot[
  torootsig[.1, x, y, .1] == 0, {x, -.1, 0.0}, {y, .093, .0999}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

To retrieve data from `cp` we evaluate

```
data = cp[[1, 1]][[1]]

Out[]= {{0., 0.0990922}, {-0.000597747, 0.0991195}, {-0.0014888, 
  0.0991607}, {-0.00279017, 0.0992146}, {-0.00357143, 
  0.0992546}, {-0.00417006, 0.0992839}, {-0.00487564, 
  0.0993172}, {-0.00535714, 0.0993408}, {-0.00590494, 
  0.0993693}, {-0.00659417, 0.0994071}, {-0.00690503, 
  0.0994236}, {-0.00714286, 0.0994372}, {-0.00786928, 
  0.0994802}, {-0.00863636, 0.0995304}, {-0.00878632, 
  0.0995402}, {-0.00892857, 0.0995513}, {-0.00946648, 
  0.099592}, {-0.00963374, 0.0996049}, {-0.00982143, 
  0.0996235}, {-0.0101356, 0.0996536}, {-0.0103567, 
  0.0996782}, {-0.0105918, 0.0997152}, {-0.0107143, 
  0.0997582}, {-0.01076, 0.0997736}, {-0.0107628, 
  0.0997768}, {-0.010754, 0.0997795}, {-0.0107143, 
  0.0997873}, {-0.0105213, 0.0998384}, {-0.0102057, 
  0.0998649}, {-0.00982143, 0.0998815}, {-0.00958534, 0.0999}}
```

These data can be used to minimize `SQ` in a case of `n=1,2`.

Comment: Nice analysis of the problem, however, I'm already aware of the non-existence of the root there, that is why I'm asking if there is any way to procedurally change the range of `FindMinimum` to avoid the problem and generate a complete list of the minimum point in a single `Table`. Your approach is also similar to my original approach to this problem, kind of manually searching for where `FindRoot` will not fail. However, I'm thinking of a general case so that if I go even below `zh<0.1`, I will have a procedure that bypasses this problem so that I don't to do it for every `n`.

Comment: There is no any general equation for your problem it is why I try to keep your code.  May be we can compute your problem in one line. Can you explain what do you try to calculate?

Comment: As in my post above, I'm calculating the point `zQ` where `SQ` is a minimum. I want to do that for some `zh`. Now I can do it one by one for every `zh` but as you see zQmin of the range `{zQ, zQmin, zQmax}` will need to be increased for lower `zh`. I already have the analysis of the problem why it does not work from the link I pasted in my post and your answer. But now, what if I want to go lower than `zh=0.1`, what if I will compute for `{zh,0.01,0.09,0.01}`? So I'm thinking maybe there is a general scheme for this problem based on the pattern of the solution above.

Comment: I used your first plot to study for example `zh=0.03`, it seems like it does not cross the x-axis even for `0.9999999 zh`. So maybe there is a `zh` where `torootsig` does not have a root already. `Plot[torootsig[0.1, x, 0.9999999 0.03, 0.03], {x, -0.005, 0.005}, PlotRange -> {-0.05, 0.05}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, ImageSize -> Large]`. The question is how to find this `zh` where `torootsig` fails to have a root.

Comment: @mathemania Your code is based on definition `sig[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] :=  x /. FindRoot[torootsig[b, x, zQ, zh], {x, -2 zh, 0},  MaxIterations -> 1000];` while there are no roots for some parameters. Therefore, first, we need to separate regions with and without roots.  Second, we need to define what to do in the case when there are no roots.

Comment: Yes, and so the smallest `zh` can be determined and obtain `sig[b_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ]` given the correct parameters.

Comment: @mathemania Ok! What to do in a case when there are no roots? Should we minimize something or just ignore your code?

Comment: If there are no roots then there is nothing to minimize so the code can just be ignored.